# Removing inline CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of javascript for a RSS feed and I want to be able to edit the CSS to my taste, however there is an existing inline style sheet over-riding my preferences.

Any ideas on how to remove the inline CSS and use an external style sheet instead?

Here is the piece of javascript that I have...

```
<!-- start feedwind code --><script type="text/javascript">document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js"><' + '/script>');</script><script type="text/javascript">(function() {var params = {rssmikle_url: "http://youtube.com/user/ReoNaomiMUA",rssmikle_frame_width: "300",rssmikle_frame_height: "400",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "off",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "20",sort: "New",rssmikle_title: "off",rssmikle_title_sentence: "",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#FF12D0",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "off",rssmikle_item_description: "title_only",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#333333",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "crop",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "player",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script>
```

Comment: `Any ideas on how to remove the inline css` => [**Idea 1**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383668/remove-inline-css-of-an-html-elements), [**Idea 2**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027935/how-to-remove-css-property-using-javascript), [**Idea 3**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033004/remove-a-specifc-inline-style-with-javascriptjquery) **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have used http://feed.mikle.com/ to create an RSS Feed Widget.

There are 3 ways in which you can customize the RSS feed.

1. Customize the widget by using http://feed.mikle.com itself.
2. Writing your own RSS reader and applying your own styles (JavaScript parser would be the easiest) [How to parse an RSS feed using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-a-rss-feed-using-javascript)
3. Editing the given JavaScript code to match your needs since the code itself contains all the style information. See below.

   ```js
   (function() {
       var params = {
           rssmikle_url: "http://youtube.com/user/ReoNaomiMUA",
           rssmikle_frame_width: "300",
           rssmikle_frame_height: "400",
           rssmikle_target: "_blank",
           rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
           rssmikle_font_size: "12",
           rssmikle_border: "off",
           responsive: "off",
           rssmikle_css_url: "",
           text_align: "left",
           text_align2: "left",
           corner: "off",
           scrollbar: "on",
           autoscroll: "off",
           scrolldirection: "up",
           scrollstep: "3",
           mcspeed: "20",
           sort: "New",
           rssmikle_title: "off",
           rssmikle_title_sentence: "",
           rssmikle_title_link: "",
           rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#0066FF",
           rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
           rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
           rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#FFFFFF",
           rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
           rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
           rssmikle_item_title_color: "#FF12D0",
           rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "off",
           rssmikle_item_description: "title_only",
           item_link: "off",
           rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
           rssmikle_item_description_color: "#333333",
           rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",
           rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",
           datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",
           item_description_style: "text+tn",
           item_thumbnail: "crop",
           article_num: "15",
           rssmikle_item_podcast: "player",
           keyword_inc: "",
           keyword_exc: ""
       };
       feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);
   })();
   ```

Comment: @TJ, what do you mean?

Comment: Is that css? doesn't look like it. There is a code block available in the editor. and please format it properly so that it's readable.

Comment: @TJ It is not CSS. It is a JavaScript code that Sam Pittman showed in the question. I used the same and highlighted where he should change as the solution. Please read the question, and answers properly.

Answer (score 0):

First port of call would be to try and modify the feed's styles using the customisation tools provided on the feed's website. Failing this, you could try to modify/remove the inline styles using JQuery after the feed has loaded on the page.

Comment: This may sound a silly question as I'm relatively new to this, but where are the inline styles picked up from? I'm only really familiar with external css etc

Comment: @SamPittman I guess they come from the code in which you want to remove them. Anyway I feel like your question is unclear.

Comment: @SamPittman As King King has said, the inline styles are part of the code which is generated, for example, inside the code you have posted, there is the following line: rssmikle_item_description_color: "#333333". This gets turned into an inline style by the script. You can modify these using JQuery once the feed has loaded.