# Overriding element.style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive web page eg where the display changes with the screen size.

I have the following HTML:

```
            <div class="responsive_menu" id="resp_Menu" onClick="fnResponsiveMenu()">
            </div>

            <div class="nav_wrapper">
                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu1">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Contact Us</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu2">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Information</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu3">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Venue Details</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu4">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Registration & Payment</a>
                </div>      

                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu5">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Agenda</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navigation" id="navMenu6">
                    <a href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

and the following in responsive.css:

```
.navigation {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3171B7;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
    margin:0;   
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px;
    height:40%;
    padding-top:10px;   
    display:none;
}
```

and the following in style.css:

```
.navigation {
    float:right;
    margin:30px 0px 1px 0px;
    height:25px;
    width:100px;    
    display:block;
}


.navigation a
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding:0 5px;
    height:30px;
}
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
var oNavChecker = 0;

function fnResponsiveMenu()
{
    if(oNavChecker == 0 )
    {
        var oNav1 = document.getElementById("navMenu1");
        oNav1.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        var oNav2 = document.getElementById("navMenu2");
        oNav2.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        var oNav3 = document.getElementById("navMenu3");
        oNav3.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        var oNav4 = document.getElementById("navMenu4");
        oNav4.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        var oNav5 = document.getElementById("navMenu5");
        oNav5.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        var oNav6 = document.getElementById("navMenu6");
        oNav6.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');

        oNavChecker = 1;
        return;
    }

    if(oNavChecker == 1 )
    {
        var oNav1 = document.getElementById("navMenu1");
        oNav1.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        var oNav2 = document.getElementById("navMenu2");
        oNav2.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        var oNav3 = document.getElementById("navMenu3");
        oNav3.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        var oNav4 = document.getElementById("navMenu4");
        oNav4.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        var oNav5 = document.getElementById("navMenu5");
        oNav5.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        var oNav6 = document.getElementById("navMenu6");
        oNav6.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');

        oNavChecker = 0;
        return;
    }

}
```

That all works fine and behaves as I want.

My problem is, once the screen has been reduced, and then the menu button pressed eg when `fnResponsiveMenu()` has been:

pressed to first show the menu

then pressed again to remove it

then the screen return to wide resolution,

The navMenus do not show anymore.

I am sure it is because the CSS is being over riden by the javascript eg:

```
oNav1.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
```

So how can I resolve this and get the style.CSS to override the changes applied by the JavaScript?

If this is not possible, can anyone suggest an alternative to achieveing my aim of making a responsive menu?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. It seems that the JS function works exactly as scripted. You have implemented a menu toggle functionality. Isin't that what you desire? If not, please explain what is your expected output.

Comment: Why the heck would you try and use JavaScript for this in the first place – instead of CSS Media Queries …?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't comment, not enought rep, so I'll ask it in the answer...

Have you read this? [Remove inline css of an HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383668/remove-inline-css-of-an-html-elements)

Once you remove inline styling, default from your css file will be applied again.